# CSS URL(); working for local files only

Tags: html, css

When I try to retrieve a font from a server and use it, it doesn't work (it finds the file but doesn't use it as the font, as shown in example one)

When I use the same file locally, it works, as shown in example 2.

I'm trying to have it use the font found on the server. How can I do that?

Example 1 (the code that doesn't work)

```css
    @font-face {
        font-family: Eurostile Extended;
        src: url("http://7poweruser.tk/Eurostile.ttf");
    }
    p{
    font-family: Eurostile Extended;
    }
```

```html
<p>test</p>
```

Example 2 (the code that works but retrieves the TTF file from a local folder):

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: Eurostile Extended;
    src: url("Eurostile.ttf"); /* This file is stored locally in the same folder as this HTML file. To download the font, visit the page in example 1. */
}
p{
font-family: Eurostile Extended;
}
</style>
<p>
test</p>
```

Comment: Font from origin 'http://7poweruser.tk' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: I would therefore recommend downloading the font and running it from your own server.

Comment: @LeeTaylor 7poweruser.tk is running on Azure. Suggestions on how to enable it on Azure?

Comment: @LeeTaylor 7poweruser.tk is my own server, I need to retrieve it from a server because I'm working on a Stylebot that changes the CSS of a webpage (such as Facebook)

Comment: I would recommend you Google CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)

Comment: http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/hosting-web-fonts-in-azure-blob-storage-using-the-new-cors-support

Comment: Yep, do what @LeeTaylor says, then it should work fine

Comment: @LeeTaylor I just added that to web.config and it is still not working

Comment: You may need to restart your web server/service

Comment: @LeeTaylor I just restarted it but it's still not working

Comment: It appears to be working for me now. Perhaps you have a cached page?

Comment: @LeeTaylor Yeah, my mistake. It works now. Thanks.